# md-input-container does not seem to be working on angular 1.3.14

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using this angular script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

but md-input-container is not properly displayed

what is the minimum angular version to be used for using this tag?

Comment: angular version is fine, did you add ng-material

Comment: no, didnt even know what is that :)

Comment: did the answer help ?

Comment: I havent the chance to verify, i ll do that ASAP and accept the answer

Comment: ok cool , it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only adding angular.js reference wont have md-input-container , you need to add the references to angular-material as well

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-aria.js"></script>
   <!-- Angular Material Javascript using RawGit to load directly from `bower-material/master` -->
    <script src="//rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>
```

Also add the dependency to your module as ,

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/JMxkXRq9956lDUwW5K8L?p=preview)**